# Possible way of implementing Constant buffer in direct x

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, directx, directx-11

I am very new to direct x programming So I am reading many articles about best way to create and manipulate Constant buffer in direct x and each of them are making me confuse ,as of now I have created a static buffer which will be updated once per frame and shared among vertex shader and one constant buffer for every object for its transformation .

```
void Scene::Render() {
    tri1.Draw();
    tri2.Draw();
}
```

and now

```
void Triangle::Draw() {
    //pCB->BindToVSshader(pContext);
    pContext->DrawIndexed(index.size(), 0, 0);
}
```

If I dont Bind constant buffer every frame for these object it just draw 1 triangle
So my question is that am I doing it right way(Bind Constant Buffer each time before draw) or is there better way of handling it

I have read article about Instancing but dont know how to Implement it or is it better than this type method and Please suggest any better way because everyone seems split about this topic